# Developing an hybrid mobile-application with google firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-apps-script, intellij-idea, hybrid-mobile-app

community :)

I am currently planning to develop an mobile-application, using google firebase as my backend. The application must be hybrid, i. e. on IOS and Android.

1. What would you recommend, how would you start the app from scratch? Do any of you know a helpful tutorial?
2. Is it possible to develop 1 code base for IOS and Android together with firebase? Or, if I want to use firebase as a backend, do I have to decide whether I want to develop an app for android or an app for IOS.

Thanks for the answer(s) : - )

Cheers

David

Comment: This question, in my opinion, should be included in this section. (https://webapps.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I recommend using ionic or apache cordova

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your questions. Usually a HYBRID solution does not mean that it will work on ANDROID and IOS, but that the codebase is partially native and partially HTML based (Cordova, React Native, Ionic, others).

Regarding your questions:

1. If you want to start from scratch, first you need to pick your development tool. If you're aiming for a single codebase for Android and iOS, I would suggest you to look at:

   - [Flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install) (you'll code in DART. Project belongs to Google)
   - [React Native](https://reactnative.dev) (you'll code in HTML/JS/CSS. Project belongs to Facebook)
   - [Mono/Xamarin](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/xamarin/mobile-apps) (you'll code in C#. Project now belongs to Microsoft)
   - [Ionic](https://ionicframework.com) (you'll code in HTML/JS/CSS)
   - [Kotlin Multiplatform](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/mobile/create-first-app.html#run-tests-on-android) (you'll code in Kotlin)
2. Yes. Totally possible. Firebase is only the backend. No matter what framework/language you pick you should be able to use Firebase as a backend.

Alternative is the native route:

1. Swift for iOS
2. Java/Kotlin for Android

Two codebases.

Answer (score 0):

You basically have two choices, you can go with a development platform which supports cross-platform, or you can maintain different code bases for both IOS and Android, by using their native development platforms. For the first choice there are a few options, React Native by Facebook and Flutter by Google are often preferred and well known cross platform development tools. If you wanna maintain different code bases for each platform, you have Android Studio for android which uses Java/Kotlin as its language, you can also go with python or C++ but they aren't famous and aren't usually preferred. Similarly apple has Xcode which uses Swift. If you wanna go with cross-platform support, React-Native only has a common UI component, the rest is still Java + Swift for individual platforms, but on the other hand Flutter compiles the code to its Native equivalent. It uses Dart, which comes from Java. Now all of these supports Firebase. If you wanna save some time, I'd recommend Flutter. It has a lot of components and makes cross-platform coding quiet easy. Cheers xD